# NodeJS Error: read ECONNRESET at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:183:27

Tags: node.js, twitter, discord

I setup a twitter real time stream bot in Discord to show any tweets of certain people in the channel. I am using pm2 to run the application on a ubuntu remove server. It seems to work for about 10 hours or so, and then the tweets don't show anymore. The other commands and the bot stay online, just the tweet function stops working. Never had this issue when I ran it on my personal PC, but it started once I started hosting it remotely. Any ideas?

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:183:27) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
```

Comment: What's the point with `discord.py` ? Btw it seems to be a connection issue `ECONNRESET`, you should also show some code.